# Concave inequality, beyond Karamata's inequality

Tags: inequality, convex-analysis

Let $0<\alpha_1 \leq \cdots \leq\alpha_m \leq \beta_1 \leq \cdots \leq \beta_n < \pi$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_i = \sum_{j=1}^n \beta_j = 2\pi.$

Can we show that $\sum_{i=1}^m \sin (\alpha_i/2) \geq \sum_{j=1}^n \sin (\beta_j/2)$?

More generally, is the following true? It looks like an improvement of Karamata's inequality in a way ($n\neq m$).

Let a convex fonction $ f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $0<\alpha_1 \leq \cdots \leq\alpha_m \leq \beta_1 \leq \cdots \leq \beta_n < 1$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_i = \sum_{j=1}^n \beta_j=1 $. Then $\sum_{i=1}^m f(\alpha_i) \leq \sum_{j=1}^n \beta_j=1 $.

Comment: I suppose in the end you mean $\sum f(\alpha_i) \le \sum f(\beta_j)$.  Not sure what the $1$ is doing there anyway - that has no resemblance to Karamata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case, note that $m> n$ and we may "pad" $m-n$ zeroes to $\{\beta_k\}$ without changing the inequality to prove.  Then as $(\underbrace{0, 0, ...0}_{m-n \text{ terms}}, \beta_1, \beta_2, ... \beta_n) \succ (\alpha_1, \alpha_2, ... \alpha_m) $ and $t \mapsto \sin t/2$ is concave, we have the result using the traditional Karamata inequality.

In the more general case you suggest, the result does **not** hold.  For instance, take $\alpha_k = 1/m$ and $\beta_k = 1/n$, then for the function $f(x)=1/x$ which is convex, the inequality reads $m^2< n^2$ which is obviously false.